# Does TensorFlow SyncReplicasOptimizer handle the problem of each worker has different batch num?

Tags: tensorflow

```
# model
train_iterator = data_reader.iterator(
                              batch_size=100,
                              shard_num=self.worker_num,
                              worker_index=self.task_index) # data parallel between device using tf.Dataset
loss = model(train_iterator.get_next())
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(opt, replicas_to_aggregate=self.worker_num, total_num_replicas=self.num_wworker_numorker, use_locking=False)
train_op = opt.minimize(train_loss)
sync_replicas_hook = opt.make_session_run_hook(self.is_chief)
hooks.append(sync_replicas_hook)

# train process
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=self.server.target,
                                       is_chief=self.is_chief,
                                       config=sess_config,
                                       hooks=hooks) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    
    # train one epoch
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            sess.run(train_op)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            if is_chief:
                saver.save(sess=sess,
                            save_path="hdfs://....../model.checkpoint." + str(epoch_num),
                            latest_filename='checkpoint.' + str(epoch_num))
            break
```

I start tensorflow with `8` workers where each worker uses `1/8` part of all data. Even each worker uses `1/8` part of all data, I can't assure every worker has the same batch num. Namely, `1/8 * all_data_num / batch_size` is different for each worker. When the chief worker waits for `replicas_to_aggregate` gradients to do allreduce, some other workers may have no data.  So the chief worker will hangs.